# Print to PDF from Acrobat PDF printer (in Windows )

Tags: pdf-format, fonts, printing

```
%%[ ProductName: Distiller ]%%
SourceSansPro-Regular not found, using Courier.
MathematicaMono-Bold not found, using Courier.
MathematicaMono not found, using Courier.
%%[Page: 1]%%
%%[ Error: invalidfont; OffendingCommand: show ]%%

Stack:
()


%%[ Flushing: rest of job (to end-of-file) will be ignored ]%%
%%[ Warning: PostScript error. No PDF file produced. ] %%
```

I know we can actually `Save As...` PDF or `Export` as PDF directly from *Mathematica*, but has anyone had the same problem when tried to print to pdf using a PDF printer like virual printer "Adobe PDF" coming with Adobe Acrobat Distiller?

I have never had any success since *Mathematica* 9.0 and now up to version 11.3. I wonder if this could be improved? It looks like a "simple" font problem?

```
OS: Windows 7 X64
```

Comment: Something like that is definitely worth an email to `support@wolfram.com`. I'm not sure anyone here is able to help you with this.

Comment: Never had any problems with this: My workflow: Print - Print as Adobe PDF, always worked.

Comment: What?! I had this problem since 9.0 and now 11.0. @mgamer what's your OS?

Comment: I also have this problem with version 11.3 on Windows 7 x64 when printing complicated graphics, for example output of `Region[ParametricRegion[{{1,0,0} + r { Cos[a], Sin[a], 0}, 0 <= r <= 1 && 0 <= a <= 2 Pi}, {a, r}]]`. I recommend reporting to the support.

Comment: Also, there is no problem when printing to "Solid PDF Creator" virtual printer.

Comment: @ChenStatsYu: MacOS 10.13.5

Comment: @mgamer Yeah. It does not work for windows at all.