# Exporting/Saving Notebook with Non English characters to PDF

Tags: export, pdf-format, fonts, character-encoding, unicode

On a [related question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/175418/print-to-pdf-from-acrobat-pdf-printer-in-windows), I now have another problem with saving notebook to PDF.

```
OS: Windows 7 SP1 English Ultimate
MMA: 11.3 X64
```

The Chinese characters displays fine in the notebook, but when exporting (`save as` PDF, this is what happened.

[image]

What can I do?? I can't `print to PDF` as stated in previous post.

Comment: I'm unable to reproduce your issue on Mac, v11.3, so my assumption is it's Windows-only

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I am on MMA 11.2 Win7-64. In order to reproduce the problem, I copied a few sentences from the Wikipedia page for MMA in Chinese (https://zh.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wolfram_Mathematica), then pasted them into MMA and changed the cell to text.

[image]

Trying to save as PDF from there produced the garbage you saw.

However, I found the problem to be the font that is used to render the characters in the Notebook. This is what worked for me:

- Select the cell containing the text
- From the menu, Format -> Font -> Arial, Regular
- Save as -> PDF

This then seems to work fine:

[image]

Comment: 谢谢！thanks! Very useful!